# Multiple Browser Windows/ Tabs As A Twilio Clients Issue

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, twilio

I am using Twilio client APIs to implement softphone in my web application. I am able to use browser for making outbound and receiving inbound calls successfully.

Used below code to generate the token required for Twilio.

```
TwilioCapability capability = new TwilioCapability(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
capability.allowClientOutgoing(applicationSid);
capability.allowClientIncoming('MY CLIENT NAME');
token = capability.generateToken(); // token works fine
```

Now, if my web page is opened in multiple browser windows/ tabs, each window/tab acts as a softphone and receives incoming call notification on each of them. (As each browser is registered with the same name - 'MY CLIENT NAME')

I want to disconnect incoming notifications on others when one of the window/ tab accepts the notification.

Any ideas. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You can simultaneously ring multiple Client windows using the [`Dial` and `Client` TwiML verbs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#nouns-client). If you assign each Client window a different name, the TwiML you need to call all of them at the same time until someone answers would look similar to the following snippet:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>window1</Client>
    <Client>window2</Client>
    <Client>window3</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```